# I/O Error during boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive

From time to time I've got an error during boot:

```
I/O Error, dev sda, sector xxxxxxx
```

Sometimes `fsck` helps me to boot up my `Ubuntu 18 system`. However, the problem come back in few days.

I tried to zero it out and `scan and remap` a disk with mhdd. Scanning pointed that there is no errorneous sectors. However, the problem still occurs.

Currently, GSmartControl shows:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       667
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   089   089   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       3463
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4426
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20258
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4246
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       457
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   059   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 17/49)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       60844
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       311
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       197746



Complete error log:

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (2 sectors)
Device Error Count: 227 (device log contains only the most recent 8 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 227 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 3a d7 98 68 e0 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x3ad79868 = 987207784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 10 00 00 3a d7 98 60 e0 08     00:00:00.060  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 10 00 00 3a d7 98 40 e0 08     00:00:00.060  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 20 00 00 3a d7 97 e0 e0 08     00:00:00.060  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 09 08 00 00 3b 57 89 00 e0 08     00:00:00.060  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3b 17 9d c0 e0 08     00:00:00.060  READ DMA EXT

Error 226 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3b168880 = 991332480

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.708  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.763  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:00.763  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08     00:00:00.763  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:00.763  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 225 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3b168880 = 991332480

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.708  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.760  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 1a 17 ab 00 40 08     00:00:00.760  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 1a 16 aa f8 40 08     00:00:00.760  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 52 16 8a d8 40 08     00:00:00.760  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 224 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3ad68880 = 987138176

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.708  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.758  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:00.758  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08     00:00:00.758  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     00:00:00.758  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 223 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3ad68880 = 987138176

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.708  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.756  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 8a c8 40 08     00:00:00.737  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 8a b8 40 08     00:00:00.737  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 10 00 00 3b 16 8a 70 40 08     00:00:00.737  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 222 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3b168880 = 991332480

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3b 16 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.671  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 51 d7 8b f8 40 08     00:00:00.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 51 17 89 88 40 08     00:00:00.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 51 17 89 38 40 08     00:00:00.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 18 00 00 51 17 89 18 40 08     00:00:00.706  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 221 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3ad68880 = 987138176

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.671  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 39 16 94 c0 40 00     00:00:00.704  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 37 97 a1 78 40 00     00:00:00.704  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 10 00 08 00 00 37 96 8d b0 40 00     00:00:00.704  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 10 00 00 3d d6 88 00 40 00     00:00:00.704  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 220 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 20256 hours (844 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 41 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3ad68880 = 987138176

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3d 96 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.673  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3a d6 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.670  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 10 00 00 3d 96 88 00 40 08     00:00:00.671  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 08 00 00 3d 56 88 80 40 08     00:00:00.671  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 10 00 10 00 00 3d 56 88 00 40 08     00:00:00.671  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

1. What is the cause of repeatable errors?
2. I suppose that the disk has a problem. Can I repair it? How to be sure that I should replace a disk (I mean- it is not caused by SATA-socket, SATA-cable, motherboard).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For the cost of a disk compared to the cost of your data and time, just replace the disk with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

That does indicate your drive had a problem but it doesn’t necessarily indicate the drive is failing and needs replacing. That is actually saying that the drive has noticed a problem and will try to correct it.

If it succeeds... happy days. If not then you’ll need to replace the drive. Offline uncorrectable value is the one you should be worried about. If that one is anything other than 0, then it’s time to replace the drive.

Additionally, if you’re using mdraid check it’s not degrading the array as that might cause you boot problems

tl;dr don’t worry. If it graduates to offline uncorrectable then worry. If you have raid then you can sit back and relax.

Comment: thanks :). However your response make me more confused. Now, I don't know whether my disk works or not. As I said in my post: From time to time kernel complains about corrupted sectors and I need to run fsck to repair ext4 filesystem. (Also, I lose some files in a result.). So, what can you say about it based on smart, log and description?

Comment: Ah sorry. Yes. You’re right I’ll edit my answer accordingly shortly. The thing to remember is you’re in a good position. You can get the system to boot. So you have a little time. If you have a raid array then swap the disk. If you don’t at least you have some time to a) perform a migration or dd etc to another disk